# Почему MediaExtractor делает ошибку AMEDIA_ERROR_BASE в одном случае и не делает в другом?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Мне нужно передать MediaExtractor-у данные, для этого я использую `setDataSource` метод, вот этот

https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#amediaextractor_setdatasourcefd

Вот так это выглядит(для примера):

```
int32_t NDK_extractor::decode()
{
   
    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    media_status_t err;
    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
    fp = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.debug/files/Models/test.mp3", "rb");


    if (fp)
    {
        err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(ex, fileno(fp), 0, dataSize);
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Failed open file");
        return 0;
    }

    if (err != AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        LOGE("SOUND :: Error setting ex data source, err %d", err);
        return 0;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

И это работает, но мне нужно работать с поинтером на дату `(void*)` и ее размером `(data_size)` для этого я пробую прочитать тот же файл получить поинтер и размер и уже работать с этим. Вот так

```
int32_t NDK_extractor::decode()
{

    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    media_status_t err;
    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
    fp = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.debug/files/Models/test.mp3", "rb");



    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long lSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    void *buf = new unsigned char[lSize];
    fread(buf, 1, lSize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fmemopen(buf, lSize, "r");
    
    
    
    if (fp)
    {
        err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(ex, fileno(fp), 0, dataSize);
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Failed open file");
        return 0;
    }

    if (err != AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        LOGE("SOUND :: Error setting ex data source, err %d", err);
        return 0;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

То есть я открываю файл читаю его получаю поинтер на бафер, открываю его `fmemopen` и так же передаю его в метод `setDataSource` и получаю ошибку `AMEDIA_ERROR_BASE`

То есть вроде все тоже самое, но что то не так, что то я упускаю тут.

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема оказалась в том, что этот метод принимает файл дескриптор как параметр для того, что получить файл дескриптор с FILE нужно вызвать вот этот метод `fileno()` и вот как оказалось, что если вызывать этот метод на файле который был открыт через `fopen()` то все работает, но если файл был открыт через `fmemopen()` то `fileno()` возвращает -1. Я пробовал сделать это через pipe https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559018/5709159 , но этот подход не работает для `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd` (я думаю потому, что pipe не поддерживает seek()) пробовал сделать через кастомный MediaExtractor (один из методов setDataSource()) , но он был введен только с api 29 (мне это не сильно подходит) в итоге сделал с костылем - получаем байты пишем во временный файл и уже открываем этот файл через `fopen()` и вызываем `fileno()` получаем файл дескриптор и передаем в `setDataSouceFd()`